# Jackson serialization of ArrayList - could there be a bug here?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize an `ArrayList` of `Map` objects into JSON format.

My problem is the order of elements in the serialized JSON list is different to the order I have defined in the `ArrayList`.

I am using Jackson 1.0.1 (I'm being forced to use such an old version because of the container that is running this code).

Could this be a bug with the Jackson serialization?

Here is my code:

```
Map<String, Object> myObject = new HashMap<String,Object>();
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
// Omitting code that populates the list...    
myObject.put("MyList", listOfMaps)
Map<String, Object>> firstElement = listOfMaps.get(0);

// Jackson serialization below:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(writer, myObject);
```

When I look at the serialized JSON,  I notice a different object appears as the first element.

Any suggestions appreciated...

Comment: Everytime I see `List<Map<String, Object>>` I have to cry. Why don't you use `List<YourClass>` ?

Comment: `myObject` is `Map<String, List<Map<String,Object>>>` ???

Comment: @seedhead - your code doesn't make sense.  The "thing" you are serializing is not even declared.  And you are putting a "list of maps" into a map.  Please provide an SSCCE if you want a proper answer.

Comment: @sanbhat Yes, one of the values in the Map is an instance of ,ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>

Comment: > Could this be a bug with the Jackson serialization? It is possible. But it is more likely a bug in your code. It looks to me that the fragments of code do not do what you (seem to) say they are doing.

Comment: It does seem strange though, that the ordering of list elements differs before and after serialization.

I literally am just constructing the object, then serializing it.

Comment: @StephenC typo in the code - fixed now. myObject is what is being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

The Java `HashMap` implementation provides no guarantee on the ordering of elements stored in it:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Jackson cannot miraculously impose order where there is none. If you want your map to be serialized in the order you inserted data into it then use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

```
Map<String, Object> myObject = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
```